# Is there a way to kill the pictured enemy?

Tags: jamestown

In the second level, Dark Sector, there is an enemy - see the picture below.
Not once have I managed to kill him - on any difficulty, neither as a single player nor in co-op. Is he invincible, or am I doing it wrong?

[image: The bastard has to be invincible!]

Comment: Which level is this, and where does it appear?

Comment: @Kotsu Level 2, towards the beginning.

Comment: I was able to take it out in solo play with the gunner ship type by keeping my directional guns focused on it. It does have an insane amount of health, so try to make sure your weapons are powered up for the duration you are shooting at it.

Comment: Note that I was unable to kill it with the Charge ship that you are using in that screenshot no matter what I tried.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Yes.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FvrUQAebOfk#t=8m46s) Try rolling with the Beam.

Comment: Thanks. In the meanwhile, I bought the Gunpowder DLC and managed it in co-op with gunpowder and ghost ships.